# Alternative to turn gem for rails MiniTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've recently upgraded to Rails 4.2.0 and MiniTest ~> 5, and that broke the Turn gem. I noticed that it is no longer being maintained due to the developers getting fed up with API changes https://github.com/turn-project/turn , so I pulled it out of my project.

I'm really missing the better test output that Turn provided. What are some great alternatives to get customizable, colorized, well-structured MiniTest output?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `minitap` and `tapout` - it's not a simple plug-and-play gem like `turn` was, but you can get it very nice with a bit of trial and error.